# Adding custom metadata in alfresco

Tags: metadata, alfresco

I added custom metadata through xml configuration specified in their wiki ... I could see the aspect I added in the /share application in manage aspects but it is not listed in /alfresco app and when i am uploading the document using the rest api  it says unable to find the field i added ..

Answer (score 2):

Share and old Alfresco Web Client have different configurations.

Check these resources out for more information:

- http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Web_Client_Customisation_Guide
- http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Displaying_Custom_Metadata

Answer (score 2):

Please read [this tutorial](http://ecmarchitect.com/archives/2012/01/09/1509) which covers creating custom content types and aspects and exposing those to both the Share (/share) and Explorer (/alfresco) web clients.

It sounds like you may have multiple problems, though, beyond configuration, because the REST API should be able to see your custom model, if it is defined correctly, regardless of whether or not it is configured in either of the two web clients.